# Can't be resolved as a type android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

It is saying that `popupWindow.OnDismissListner` Can't be resolved as a type and when I hover the mouse over it the only option I get is to make it an interface, which isn't what I want to do.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener,     
PopupWindow.OnDismissListener, View.OnClickListener {
```

I am unsure exactly what is wrong. I imported `android.widget.PopupWindow.OnDismissListener;` and it still is giving the error. I am trying to get a menu to pop up with a list of dice and when a dice is clicked it will return a matching int value based on how many sides the dice has. I have no other errors except the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
import android.widget.PopupWindow.OnDismissListener;
```

with

```
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
```

Or simply use `OnDismissListener` in your code (not `PopupWindow.OnDismissListener`).

Comment: Those gave me unreachable code errors in other places of my code. They are unrelated in that they are not using .dismiss() or anything like that at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "Those"?

Comment: using the methods you provided to fix my posted problem. Sorry for the lack of clarification. I would post my whole code but it is almost 3 hundred lines long

Comment: Did these methods solved "Can't be resolved as a type" problem?  If yes then simply ask a different question about a different problem :)